# Can you change the default functionality for Tortoise SVN update to stop recursive updates?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So, I know in the subversion client you can stop the recursion in the update command using the following:

```
svn update --depth=files
```

and this functionality also exists within TortoiseSVN.

However, I want this to be the default functionality of update.   Such that, if a user runs the command

```
svn update
```

It only updates that directory and/or file and does not recursively update the subdirectories.   I would want this to be the default functionality for the entire machine, no matter what repository was checked out.  If that is not possible, can we default that functionality for each repository we check out?

The main objective here to stop anyone from accidently updating the entire directory tree.   They should be forced to update one file/directory at a time.

Thanks is advance for you help.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by requiring people to only update one file/directory at a time? It sounds like an impediment to working efficiently. Let's address this requirement before attempting to change the behavior of the client.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As I stated in the problem, the main objective here is to keep someone from accidently updating the entire tree.   If the code in other subdirectories is not ready to be placed on this server, we don't want it to end up there.  While inefficient, we believe this safety measure removes enough risk to warrant the extra effort.

Comment: Yes, you stated your objective but not what that objective was attempting to address. You should expand upon that in your question. That said, you're taking a backwards approach to preventing code from getting on your server - you need a better feature/bugfix branching strategy and proper change/release management processes. What you propose will only slow someone down, it won't stop them from putting out a bad release. Purely technical solutions to people/procedural/organizational problems are very hard to get right.

Comment: Yes, perhaps you are correct.  We need to go back and review are strategy and find another solution.   Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glossing over my objections to this approach that I noted in my comment, no, Subversion does not natively provide for this AFAIK. Your options:

- Create a custom svn binary which defaults to your preferred update depth. Risk: users revert back to the standard binary by keeping a copy in their home directory, working via a UNC path or other remote filesystem access, using an alternative client, or using the standard client still installed on the system  but in a non-default/overridden path.
- Create a global shell script and/or alias for svn which specifies your preferred update depth. Risks: See above.